# How to center the contents of a cell at the left at the center

Tags: tables, overleaf

How to do it? Using the code below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{| c | m{150pt} | p{150}|}
  \hline
 1 & one & one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one  \\ \hline
  2 & two  & two two two two two two two two one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one \\ \hline
  3 & three  & three \\ \hline
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple: use two `m` column types, not one:

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{array}
    \usepackage{longtable}
    \usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{longtable}{| c | m{150pt} | m{150pt}|}
      \hline
     1 & one & one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one \\ \hline
      2 & two & two two two two two two two two one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one \\ \hline
      3 & three & three \\ \hline
    \end{longtable}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yeah, seems like it works.

Comment: Of course, I've tested this solution before posting.